# Including .h files OpenCV

Tags: opencv, header, include

I have read the related questions but I cannot solve my problem.

I'm trying to compile a OpenCV C++ code on raspberry pi.

OpenCV requires cv.h to be included. When I try to compile I get:

"fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory."

I have tried these:

```
g++ -c -Ihome/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv file.cpp
g++ -c -Ipi/OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv file.cpp
g++ -c -IOpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv file.cpp
```

Do any of you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question and not related only to OpenCV. 
For the general problem of including any header file
1. Try to see if the file is really at the included directory or no
2. Try to look for it in the folder